# How to End multiple if statements on one line

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to end 2 if statements on **one line**.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If showing = True Then
            Do
                txtpassword.Text = ""
                If txtpassword.Text = password Then
                    My_Private_Screen.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    showing = False
                    attempts = 0
                ElseIf txtpassword.Text = "" Then
                    Do
                        If txtpassword.Text = password Then
                            My_Private_Screen.Show()
                            Me.Hide()
                        End If
                    Loop Until Inc = 5
                    Me.Hide()
                    showing = False
                    Do

                    Loop Until Inc2 = 300
                    Me.Show()
                    showing = True
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password")
                    attempts = attempts + 1
            Loop Until attempts = 5
            Me.Hide()
        End If

        showing = False
```

So I need to know how to end 2 ifs. I want to know how to do something like this:

```
        Me.Hide()
   End If
   End If
```

Or

```
 Me.Hide()
   End If End If
```

Comment: You cant thats not how vs parses the statements, also the code above wont compile... And when you do, youll have a stack overflow exception...

Comment: You can end multiple `If` on one line: `End If : End If`. But the logic of your code won't allow it even if you wanted to, since you want to end the If outside a loop which starts inside it.

Comment: oh ok i just thought that might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the inner If before the loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If showing = True Then
        Do
            txtpassword.Text = ""
            If txtpassword.Text = password Then
                My_Private_Screen.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                showing = False
                attempts = 0
            ElseIf txtpassword.Text = "" Then
                Do
                    If txtpassword.Text = password Then
                        My_Private_Screen.Show()
                        Me.Hide()
                    End If
                Loop Until Inc = 5
                Me.Hide()
                showing = False
                Do

                Loop Until Inc2 = 300
                Me.Show()
                showing = True
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password")
                attempts = attempts + 1
            Endif
        Loop Until attempts = 5
        Me.Hide()
    End If

    showing = False
```